# put_user() linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel

After doing `put_user(message[i], buf+i);`
how can I access message from user space?

I really don't understand where the string message is to be accessed from and what I can do with it?

Comment: What syscall are you using to tickle this?

Comment: it is similar to `copy_to_user`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265657/how-does-copy-from-user-from-the-linux-kernel-work-internally but for a single value: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33182877/applicaiton-of-get-user-when-there-is-copy-from-user

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`put_user (x, ptr)`. Here `x` is the value to copy to user space, while `ptr` is the destination address, in user space.

So in user application the message can be accessed by `buf+i`.

Answer (score 8):

`put_user()` should only be called in the context of a process making a system call.

Consider an application calling `ptrace(2)` (see `kernel/ptrace.c`).

The kernel will call into an architecture-specific `ptrace` helper:

```
SYSCALL_DEFINE4(ptrace, long, request, long, pid, unsigned long, addr,
            unsigned long, data) 
{
    /* arch-independent code */
    /* ... */
    ret = arch_ptrace(child, request, addr, data);
```

On the x86 platform, `arch_ptrace()` is defined in `arch/x86/kernel/ptrace.c`:

```
long arch_ptrace(struct task_struct *child, long request,
             unsigned long addr, unsigned long data)
{
    int ret;
    unsigned long __user *datap = (unsigned long __user *)data;

    switch (request) {
    /* read the word at location addr in the USER area. */
    case PTRACE_PEEKUSR: {
            unsigned long tmp;

            ret = -EIO;
            if ((addr & (sizeof(data) - 1)) || addr >= sizeof(struct user))
                    break;

            tmp = 0;  /* Default return condition */
            if (addr < sizeof(struct user_regs_struct))
                    tmp = getreg(child, addr);
            else if (addr >= offsetof(struct user, u_debugreg[0]) &&
                     addr <= offsetof(struct user, u_debugreg[7])) {
                    addr -= offsetof(struct user, u_debugreg[0]);
                    tmp = ptrace_get_debugreg(child, addr / sizeof(data));
            }
            ret = put_user(tmp, datap);
            break;
    }
```

When a process calls `ptrace(2)` and asks to perform a `PTRACE_PEEKUSR`, the kernel needs to return information (`ret`) back to the user. The kernel uses the `datap` pointer to a **user supplied buffer** to know where in the process to write the value of `tmp`.

Almost every case of calling `put_user()` will be initiated **by a userland process**. Sending signals to userspace is an obvious difference, where the kernel initiates sending the signal, but the kernel has code (see `arch/x86/kernel/signal.c` function `__setup_frame()`) to find the stack frame and write into it the need to handle a signal.

So, after a long-winded discussion: You will access your data in your process via *whatever buffer you gave to the kernel to write into* -- it could be a buffer for a driver-specific `ioctl(2)`, it could be a buffer argument to a new system call you create, you have a lot of choices.