# copy_from_user() failed for intel x-86 processor but execute fine to ppc e500 processor

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel, linux-device-driver, ioctl

I am working on Linux Kernel Usrspace and Kernel space communication,

I am using two target boards,
1) Board with PPC -e500 processor 
2) Board with intel x-86 processor

Following peace of code working on e500 processor but same code is giving kernel error after IOCTL call execution as

```
*error: returning IOCTL -1073460967 ERROR as -EFAULT, kernel error: 28*     

 //User space call
 retVal = ioctl( FD, SOME_OPERATION, &myInfo );
```

//Definition of structures

```
struct user_space_struct
{
   unsigned long A;
   unsigned long B;  //file descriptor
   unsigned long C;
   unsigned long D;
   unsigned long E;
   unsigned long F;
   unsigned long G;
};



ret = copy_from_user( (void *)&kernel_space_struct,(void *)arg, sizeof(struct    user_space_struct) );
```

//Kernel space call

```
    if( ret != 0 ) {
        printk("In Kernel space copy_from_user() failed \n");
        break;
    }
```

Can anyone please help me to understand why I am getting this error.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the definition of struct `user_space_struct`?  And of myInfo? Could you be running into struct padding differences across the kernel boundary, so that `sizeof(struct user_space_struct)` isn't the correct value?

Comment: @peter .. Thanks for input.  The definition of user_space_struct and myInfo is same. Both borads 1) Board with PPC -e500 processor and 2) Board with intel x-86 processor are having 32 bit operating system. Could you please let me know how check Padding differences accross the kernel boundary and also can you suggest how avoid it....Thanks! :)

Comment: Paste the entire struct definition into your question.

Comment: @Peter ..Thanks for you help peter. I have pasted entire struct definition in my question (user_space_struct)

Comment: @peter .. Also I printed size of sizeof(struct epc_diskop_ioctl_param) and sizeof(infoD) both are equal to 28 bytes.

Comment: Those all look fine.  The problem must lie elsewhere, and you haven't supplied enough code to guess at where.

Comment: @Peter :: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265657/internal-working-of-copy-from-user  ...Can this be reason for the copy_from_user failure ...?

Comment: It explains HOW the faults are being generated.  But you don't really care about the mechanism.  We can assume that copy_from_user is working properly, and that it is reporting an actual error in memory allocation, addressing, length, and/or alignment.  Consider testing a simpler case, perhaps transferring just a single integer.