# IOCTL error while passing struct to driver

Tags: c, linux, driver, linux-device-driver

I am trying to pass a struct pwmData type variable to my driver through ioctl. But in my app I get an Invalid Argument error through perror.
Can someone please tell me why I am getting this?
My .h file:

```
typedef struct
 {
      unsigned int pwmChannel;
      unsigned int pwmDutyCycle;
      unsigned int pwmPeriod;
  }pwmData;  

#define PWM_MAGIC '0xF2'  //Is not used in kernel, hence used here
#define ENABLE_PWM _IOW(PWM_MAGIC, 1,pwmData*)
#define DISABLE_PWM _IOW(PWM_MAGIC, 2,pwmData*)
```

My app(where fd is my file descriptor):

```
pwmData param;
param.pwmPeriod = 1000;
param.pwmDutyCycle = 500;
param.pwmChannel = 1;

  ret = ioctl(fd, ENABLE_PWM, &param); // Check casting
  if(ret<0){
    printf("ENABLE IOCTL failed %d.\n", ret);
    perror("Error:");
    exit(-1);
  }
```

My driver's ioctl part:

```
static long pwm_device_ioctl(struct file *f, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
    printk(KERN_DEBUG "Entered IOCTL\n");
    int retval;
    static pwmData* data;
    data = (void *)kmalloc(sizeof(pwmData)+1,GFP_KERNEL);

    switch (cmd)
    {
        case ENABLE_PWM:
        if(copy_from_user((void*)data, (void*)arg, sizeof(pwmData)))
        {
            return -EFAULT;
        }

printk(KERN_DEBUG "%d %d %d\n",data->pwmChannel,data->pwmDutyCycle,data->pwmPeriod);

    retval = pwm_config(&cpwm1->chip.pwms[(data->pwmChannel) - 1], data->pwmDutyCycle, data->pwmPeriod);
    if(retval == 0)
    {
        retval = pwm_enable(&cpwm1->chip.pwms[(data->pwmChannel) - 1]);
        return retval;
    }
    else
    {
        return retval;
    }
    break;
```

And similarly for PWM_DISABLE.
I have just started linux driver devel. so any suggestions would be apprectiated.

Comment: Are you basically asking why your driver return an error ?

Comment: I don't know much about the topic but `copy_from_user` has been discussed on SO [for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265657/how-does-copy-from-user-from-the-linux-kernel-work-internally)

Comment: is there any easier way other than ioctl to copy data to driver while still using switch case?

Comment: Could you please show the rest of the second snippet. Say, `copy_from_user()` returns `0` and we complete `switch()` step successfully. What is returned in the end?

Comment: just ran dmesg..turns out that values are getting printed so either pwm_config or pwm_enable is failing