# application of get_user when there is copy_from_user

Tags: linux-kernel, operating-system, kernel

In Linux kernel programming, I see **get_user** and **copy_from_user** perform read from user space, earlier one reads fixed 1, 2 or 4 bytes while latter reads arbitrary number of bytes from user space. What was the need of get_user? Did copy_from_user come after get_user and hence get_user was kept for backward compatibility? Are there *specific applications* of get_user or is it obsolete now? Same queries for put_user and copy_to_user.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can think about

```
copy_from_user(dest, src, size);
```

as some sort of

```
memcpy(dest, src, size);
```

and about

```
get_user(x, ptr);
```

as some sort of simple assignment:

```
x = *ptr;
```

Like a *simple assignment* is a cleaner(for code undestanding), shorter and faster way than a `memcpy()` function call, `get_user` is a cleaner, shorter and faster way than a `copy_from_user`.

The mostly known case, when the size of the data is constant and small(so `get_user` is applicable), is an `ioctl` implementation for devices. You can find many `get_user` usages by `grep`-ing kernel sources for `get_user`, or using online kernel code search service like [Linux Cross Reference](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/ident/get_user).